# Detecting if a user tapped a macOS push notification while the application is already open

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, push-notification

I cannot figure out if a macOS application got active again because of tapping on a push notification or simply by reopening it again in another way.

I have an application that allows the users to chat with each other amongst other things. To remind the user of a new message I send them push notifications either when the app is not running or when the application is running but not active. When they have the app active it will show the notification internally and no notification is shown in the notification center.

When it's not running I can open my application from a push notification and figure out who sent the message in what conversation because it'll give you all the details in the aNotification Notification in applicationDidFinishLaunching so I know I have to perform something special immediately after launching like opening a certain chat.

But when the application is already running it'll call didReceiveRemoteNotification first, and when I open the application from the push notification there's no way to distinguish it from a regular tap on the application icon to get focus again or tapping the push notification in applicationDidBecomeActive. In iOS the application will always either be visible or coming from the background, this distinction doesn't exist so clearly on a desktop.

I need to know the application became active again because the user tapped a push notification and if so what the payload was of that notification so I can route the user to the right screen immediately.